# Creating a Generic instance of type in Java

Tags: java, generics, types, interface, instance

I have the following Java class

```
public class MyClass <T extends MyInterface> implements RowMapper<MyInterface>
```

I'm implementing the following method:

```
@Override
public T mapRow(ResultSet rs, int arg1) throws SQLException {
```

**How can I create an instance of 'T' type on that class?**

I tried to define the T type class and use "myInstance.newInstance()" but I was unable to define it. Sending the Class as a parameter to the method and using the "newInstance()" method works, but I want to be able to do so without having to pass it as a param.
Thanks!

Comment: any class that extends MyInterface will represent T. So create class and extend it with MyInterface. Create instance of that new class then.

Comment: Why do you assume `T` even has a default constructor?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Java generics are implemented by erasure which means there will be no parameter type information at runtime. You won't know the T class at runtime (there is not such T.class). So you need to pass the `Class` object as a method parameter in order to do what you want.

Comment: Heck, this has been asked a million times in SO, but this is the only answer that actually goes to the point (albeit could start with a straight **you can't**). Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Bruno - million times is about right, and one would think that the Java designers would take the hint and add that to the java's reflection already...

Answer (score 10):

You are loosing all information about type when passing object into generic class/function.

The only way you can do this - pass `Class` object to constructor\function:

```
static class Gen <T>{

    private Class<T> mClass;

    public Gen(Class<T> cls){
        mClass = cls;
    }

    public T get(){
        try{
            return mClass.newInstance();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}

static class A{
    public String name = "A!";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gen<A> g = new Gen<A>(A.class);
    A a = g.get();
    System.out.println(a.name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, due to type erasure, you can't do what you want.

You will have to explicitly tell your class which type it needs to instantiate, either by telling it the `Class` or, perhaps more elegantly, giving it a Factory to create instances.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to extract the class to which T was bound in a particular sub-class, though that's not very easy:

http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpostP.jsp?thread=208860

I've a slightly better version of the code in that post here:

http://github.com/ISA-tools/jUtils/blob/master/src/main/java/uk/ac/ebi/utils/reflection/ReflectionUtils.java

http://github.com/ISA-tools/jUtils/blob/master/src/test/java/uk/ac/ebi/utils/reflection/ReflectionUtilsTest.java

This approach isn't much fast either, so if performance is a concern, an rougher alternative could be to pass T and an instance of Class<T> too where you need.

Of course after having got such class, you need to use reflection to instantiate it.